# how can i change a form element depending on which image is selected

Tags: html, paypal, onclick

I have code below which changes price is the 'price' div to what the user selects.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function showprice(e){
            document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = e.getAttribute('data-price');
        }
    </script>

        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/JnUKx.jpg" id="img1" onclick="showprice(this);" width="39" height="33" data-price="245.00">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/c8Rwp.gif" id="img2" onclick="showprice(this);" width="39" height="33" data-price="255.00">

        <div id="price" style="padding-bottom:10px"></div>​
```

I have created 2 separate paypal buttons for each price. Both buttons are exactly the same but each have a different 'value'. how can i change the 'value' depending on which image the user selects?

value for img1 button @ £245 is SKF4F8AARZWKE (code below)
value for img1 button @ £265 is WEI8F8HHJOPRY

paypal code for button img1 value SKF4F8AARZWKE

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

                  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="SKF4F8AARZWKE">

  <input type="image" src="images/buyitnow.png"  style="width:100px; height:30px" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal — The safer, easier way to pay online.">

            </form>​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the input element an id and use document.getElementById('YOUR_ID').value = 'YOUR VALUE';

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function changeprice(e){
        document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = e.getAttribute('data-price');
        document.getElementById("hosted_button_id").value = e.getAttribute('data-value');
   }
</script>

<img src="http://i.imgur.com/JnUKx.jpg" id="img1" onclick="changeprice(this);" width="39" height="33" data-price="245.00" data-value="SKF4F8AARZWKE">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/c8Rwp.gif" id="img2" onclick="changeprice(this);" width="39" height="33" data-price="255.00" data-value="WEI8F8HHJOPRY">

<div id="price" style="padding-bottom:10px"></div>​


<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" id="hosted_button_id" name="hosted_button_id" value="SKF4F8AARZWKE">

    <input type="image" src="images/buyitnow.png"  style="width:100px; height:30px" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal — The safer, easier way to pay online.">
</form>​
```

Comment: thank but that did not work, it is just doing the same button value for each image?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. In my code, clicking on the images (img1 or img2) will change the value of the hidden input field `hosted_button_id` to the `data-value` attribute of the clicked image. http://jsfiddle.net/5HGfQ/ . Which form element would you like to change instead?

Comment: i want to change the 'value' in this line of code:"     <input type="hidden" id="hosted_button_id" name="hosted_button_id" value="SKF4F8AARZWKE">

Comment: The value of that input field is changed when you click on the image. See the working demo http://jsfiddle.net/5HGfQ/

Comment: Ah great got it now. if I was to add a colour (white and black) like so http://jsfiddle.net/5HGfQ/2/. I have created a paypal button for each scenario i.e. white & small, black & large etc, each having a different 'value' how would I implement that into the code?

Comment: could you help me with the issue above?

Comment: Please provide more details, what should happen when white and small is clicked. What value should be sent?